# Why 400 error code in POST call using Jersey client

Tags: java, rest, jersey, rest-client, jersey-client

I am calling a post request using Jersey rest client which contains no request body  but contains authorization header. I am always getting 400 error. I tried from postman i got 200 response. Here is my code

```
ClientResponse response = null;
Client cliente=Client.create();
cliente.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));
WebResource webResource=cliente.resource("https://URL/token");
Builder builder = webResource.accept("application/json");
builder.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
builder.header("Authorization", "Basic YbjjkwliOTQtNjRiYy00NWE5LWFhMzQtMTFhNDkyZZjNTVlOjZjYjk2OTMwNGE5YTQ3OTlhODVjZTM5MDFiMDEyMTI2";
builder.post(ClientResponse.class,Entity.json(""));
```

Comment: I don't know much about Jersey, but a basic auth header needs a space between the string "Basic" and the B64 credentials. I would assume there is a way of getting Jersey to generate this header from a configured username/password though, rather than hard-coding it.

Comment: Doesn't matter what the client is, the servers need the space because it is part of the HTTP specification https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945#section-10.16

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the way you are trying right now. Use HttpAuthenticationFeature from Jersey like this

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("username", "password");

 

final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

client.register(feature);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 200 success respone  in postman and failure response in your application then you need to check your api with another api tester online tool. I had the same issue i put / at the last of end point.